# Checking algorithm with two conditions in ranges

Tags: algorithm, vba, excel

I have a problem with checking algorithm with two conditions in ranges...
I want to assign a value after checking the two conditions in ranges...

Example:
[image]

I want to assign a value to column D... and I have numbered ranges with ID (1,2,3...). Column B have value only near ID = 1, next ID is null, but all rows in range have character.
So, I need to assign a value to column D according to the table next to.
When column B have TRUE then value in column D = NEGATIVE... end, but when value in column B = FALSE check combination in range.

Expected result:
[image]

Do you have an idea? Thanks for help!

Comment: ...just commenting as I read... "next ID is null" is impossible for there are no NULL cell values in Excel...

Comment: Do you want to solve this via VBA or formulas?

Comment: via VBA I tried use formulas but no effect... Can you solved this via formulas?

Comment: either way works, hoever formula seems more suited for this problem

Comment: hi, I think you need to give more details about what if value in B column is false. because the table which you referred is not understandable. If value in B column is "TRUE", D is definatelly "NEGATIVE". What about if it is "FALSE"?

Comment: When FALSE then I check characters in range (column C): POSITIVE = (POSITIVE) or (POSITIVE, NEUTRAL) or (POSITIVE,POSITIVE...); NEGATIVE (ever when is NEGATIVE without POSITIVE in range result = NEGATIVE); MIX = (POSITIVE, NEGATIVE) or (POSITIVE,NEGATIVE,NEUTRAL) or (POSITIVE,POSITIVE,NEGATIVE,POSITIVE...) and NEUTRAL (when is only NEUTRAL - (NEUTRAL) or (NEUTRAL,NEUTRAL,NEUTRAL)

Comment: Now it is more clear however I think it is not possible with formulas. You need to go for VBA, unless someone here can provide this to you with formula. For VBA you can start with some While/For loops and range management. I do not know how much you know about VBA, if you try something and update your topic with your trials, I am sure people (including myself) will help you to improve it but I am not sure if someone will write if for you from scratch.

Comment: I tried via VBA, but I dont know how take a range. In first loop range will have two cells, next four, next only one. Here I have a problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And boom goes the dynamite.  This will take an input like this:

[image]

And give you this:

[image]

```
Sub TestIt()

Dim LastRow As Long, CurRow As Long, InLast As Long, FindRng As Range

LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = 1 To LastRow
    If Not Range("B" & CurRow).Value = "" Then
        If Range("B" & CurRow + 1).Value = "" Then
            InLast = Range("B" & CurRow).End(xlDown).Row - CurRow - 1
        Else
            InLast = 0
        End If
        If InLast > LastRow Then InLast = LastRow - CurRow
        If InLast > 0 Then Set FindRng = Range(Cells(CurRow, 3), Cells(InLast + CurRow, 3))
        Select Case True
            Case Range("B" & CurRow).Value = "TRUE"
                Range("D" & CurRow).Value = "NEGATIVE"
            Case InLast = 0
                Range("D" & CurRow).Value = Range("C" & CurRow).Value
            Case Not FindRng.Find("POSITIVE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
                    And Not FindRng.Find("NEGATIVE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
                    And Not FindRng.Find("NEUTRAL", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
                    And InLast > 0
                Range("D" & CurRow).Value = "MIX"
            Case Not FindRng.Find("POSITIVE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
                    And FindRng.Find("NEGATIVE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
                    And InLast > 0
                Range("D" & CurRow).Value = "POSITIVE"
            Case FindRng.Find("POSITIVE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
                    And Not FindRng.Find("NEGATIVE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
                    And InLast > 0
                Range("D" & CurRow).Value = "NEGATIVE"
            Case FindRng.Find("POSITIVE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
                    And FindRng.Find("NEGATIVE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
                    And Not FindRng.Find("NEUTRAL", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
                    And InLast > 0
                Range("D" & CurRow).Value = "NEUTRAL"
            'Case Not FindRng.Find("POSITIVE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
            '        And Not FindRng.Find("NEGATIVE", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
            '        And FindRng.Find("NEUTRAL", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing _
            '        And InLast > 0
            '    Range("D" & CurRow).Value = "CASE POSITIVE AND NEGATIVE NO NEUTRAL"
            Case Else
                Range("D" & CurRow).Value = "ERROR"
        End Select
    End If
Next CurRow

End Sub
```

Comment: It's brilliant! but when I have four times 'POSITIVES' result is 'ERROR' and should be 'POSITIVE'. Why? meritorious green checkmark!

Comment: @user3815737 Try now.  Updated to remove the Neutral condition on Positive and Negative found (because either way you want Positive or Negative).  You did forget the condition where you have Positive and Negative but no Neutral.  That isn't in your table!

Comment: @user3815737 I have added BUT COMMENTED OUT the case of Positive and Negative but no Neutral.  You will need to assign a result to it and remove the comment `'`

Comment: You're my master! Thanks bro!

Comment: I can't move this discussion to chat :( I'm working with code and in situation when I have only single ranges code crazy. VBA sees the range as all. Can you check this case? Try run the macro without spaces in column B

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B1),"", IF(B1="TRUE", "NEGATIVE", C1))
```

Comment: this is yet another implementation of the same logic--a very good learning moment for the OP

Comment: This solved problem first problem when B1=TRUE, but else I need check range (1,2,3,4), (POSSITIVE, POSITIVE, NEGATIVE, NEUTRAL) = MIX. I need to assign a value to column D according to the table next to - table combination.

Comment: Sorry, I had problem to understand how your columnA worked with columnC. Could you provide a truth table or a better explanation?

Answer (score 1):

The formula in "D1" is a s follows:

```
=IF(B1=TRUE,"NEGATIVE",IF(B1="","", C1))
```

Paste down form "D1"